# Can I use the <video> tag to stream videos stored on Ubuntu One?

Tags: video, streaming

I have a few videos on Ubuntu One cloud web storage and want to play that videos on my blog using  html tag without downloading.  Because my friend wants to see them withut downloading.  When I enter the video URL in Firefox address bar the video stream's and played, but when I use the `<video>` tag it gives me an error:

```
contains mime type is not found!
```

Any body have an idea to play directly Ubuntu One videos in my blog page?
thank's

Comment: videos are in mp4 format and h.264/aac codec

Comment: Can you add the HTML you used please?

Comment: <video width="800" height="600" controls>
<source src="http://ubuntuone.com/2GefkbArwA2wtiZTWahXAy">
</video>

Comment: and <video width="800" height="600" controls> <source src="ubuntuone.com/2GefkbArwA2wtiZTWahXAy" type="video/mp4"></video>

Comment: any idea?
please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firefox does not support MP4](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) for the `<video>` tag.  You will need to convert your video into `Ogg` or `WebM` for Firefox to read it.  I recommend using `WebM` as it has the smallest file format.

Install "Ogg Convert":

```
sudo apt-get install oggconvert
```

Make sure you have a local copy of your video.

1. Open Ogg Convert and select your video file.

[image]

2: Make sure "Vido Format" is set to `VP8`.

3: Click "Advanced" and set "File Format" to `WebM`

[image]

4: Add a name for the file under "File Name" and select a folder to save it too.

5: Click "Convert".

6:  Upload the converted file to Ubuntu One.

You're HTML should now look something like this:

```
<video width="800" height="600" controls>
  <source src="ubuntuone.com/2GefkbArwA2wtiZTWahXAy" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="link_To_Webm_File" type="video/webm">
 </video>
```

Comment: @user127063 If this solved your problem, please [accept](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/44179) the answer so this thread gets marked as answered.  Thanks!

Comment: sorry!
but the problem is not sloved :(
please go this link with firefox and opera:
http://blog.ma3x.ir/node/9
video will successfully play in chrome but will not play in firefox and opera!
what is the problem?
thanks

Comment: @user127063 Firefox couldn't decode your video.  Are you sure you set "Format" to `VP8` and "File Format" to `WebM`?  I suggest trying again.

Comment: yes!
if you not sure, you can download it by this link: http://ubuntuone.com/3ObFuwccGuX9iUQ7Igif0a
the video codec is: VP8 and audio codec is: Vorbis
thank you so moch

Comment: wait! the video format is "webm", not "WebM"! is there a problem?!

Comment: have you any idea for this issue?!
i'm so sorry for waisting your time  and my bad english!

Comment: @user127063 Hmm, Firefox certainly thinks it is corrupt.  Can you provide me with the original MP4?  I will try converting it myself.  As well as try `Ogg` which Firefox also supports.

Comment: finally use "OGG" format and that works!

Comment: I am still surprised WebM didn't work...  glad OGG did though!